# Grep exits abnormally with code 123 when running rgrep on emacs

Tags: linux, emacs, grep, xargs

Greetings fellow Emacsers

I'm running GNU Emacs 23.1.1 on "Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS" and any search I perform using the built-in M-x rgrep on the standard Linux kernel source code (vanilla) ends prematurely with the following error printed to the emacs echo area:

```
Grep exited abnormally with code 123
```

I have been seeing it for a while on Redhat systems as well, and with other (large) code bases, Anybody seen or even better cured that?

Thanks!

Edit: for reasons beyond me stackexchange does not allow me to edit my comment below so I'll update here.

following the comment below I have tried to run the same command that rgrep runs in an emacs shell buffer

```
 find . \( -path \*/SCCS -o -path \*/RCS -o -path \*/CVS -o -path \*/MCVS -o -path \*/.svn -o -path \*/.git
-o -path \*/.hg -o -path \*/.bzr -o -path \*/_MTN -o -path \*/_darcs -o -path \*/\{arch\} \) -prune -o  -type f \( -name \*.\[ch\] \) -p
rint0 | xargs -0 -e grep -i -nH -e v4l_compat_ioctl32
```

while it does not print any error, interrogating the exit code shows the same 123 again.

```
/home/mcradle/linux> echo $?
123
```

following the comment from Gilles I've tried to run

```
/home/mcradle/linux> find . -type f \( -name \*.\[ch\] \) -exec grep -i -nH -e v4l_compat_ioctl32 '{}' \;
```

which is functionally equivalent to the find and xargs combination and it completed with exit code 0

```
/home/mcradle/linux> echo $?
0
```

so it does seems to be something with xargs.

Comment: `M-x rgrep` runs `find … | xargs grep …`, and 123 means that at least one of `xargs`'s invocations of `grep` returned a non-zero error code. If this happens only in large code bases, it might be related to `xargs` invoking more than one instance of `grep` (perhaps one instance finds no file?). Is a `*grep*` buffer created?

Comment: it does open the ***grep*** buffer even shows a bunch of results and then prints "Grep exited abnormally with code 123 at ..."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at xargs exit code documentation:

```
123 if any invocation of the command exited with status 1-125
```

but according to grep documentation 1 is the exit status if grep didn't match the pattern

```
EXIT STATUS
   Normally, the exit status is 0 if selected lines are found and 1 otherwise.
```

So to me it seems that the command line that emacs uses to issue an 'rgrep' search will always return 123, and this error either needs to be suppressed or replaced with a command line such as

```
find . -type f \( -name \*.\[ch\] \) -exec grep -i -nH -e v4l
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to do a recursive grep through a bunch of C .c and .h files, while ignoring directories used by version control systems.  You want ack.  See http://betterthangrep.com/

The command to do exactly what you are doing, in ack:

```
ack --cc -i v4l_compat_ioctl32
```

The effects of -r, -n and -H are assumed in ack.  The -i is still case-insensitive, and --cc says "Search *.c and *.h files only"

No need for find.  No need for xargs.  Just a version of Perl installed and a single Perl program, with no external modules.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I have ack installed but never came around to download and install ack.el for emacs, I might do eventually.